# Should I include .vcxproj files with open source C++ projects?

Tags: github, source-code

I am working on developing some libraries in C++, and I was wondering whether I should include my `.vcxproj` files that Visual Studio creates in my project's GitHub repository.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! They make It easy to build the project. Source code includes those things commonly needs to create a binary which are very individual to your project - like  project files or built and configure scripts